# How to set a variable equal to zero based on a conditional if-then statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a Python script (IDLE) to make a nutrient recommendation, with the following formula:

`potassium_recommendation = (73 + (yieldGoal * 0.21) + (soilPotassium * -0.565) + (yieldGoal * soilPotassium * -0.0016))`

The output of this specific equation tells the user how much potassium a user needs to meet a crop yield goal, and will later be used to calculate a specific amount of fertilizer that needs to be applied.

For this example, let's say that yieldGoal = 200, and soilPotassium = 500.

If you start the growing season with a higher soil potassium level than the crop takes from the soil, you don't need to make a nutrient application. You know this is the case if the equation yields a negative number.

I want to build a conditional statement that sets the `potassium_recommendation` variable equal to zero if a negative number is reached. How can I do that?

Here is what I have tried:

```
potassium_recommendation = (73 + (200 * 0.21) + (500 * -0.565) + (200 * 500 * -0.0016))

        if potassium_recommendation < 0 == True:
            potassium_recommendation = 0
        else:
            potassium_recommendation = potassium_recommendation

print potassium_recommendation
```

When I run this code, it still produces a negative number. How can I make it zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove '== True' part in if statement

```
potassium_recommendation = (73 + (200 * 0.21) + (500 * -0.565) + (200 * 500 * -0.0016))
if potassium_recommendation < 0:
    potassium_recommendation = 0

print( potassium_recommendation)
```

Answer (score 3):

A more compact approach is to use the [math.max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)(MIN_VALUE, VALUE):

```
potassium_recommendation = max(0, 73 + (200 * 0.21) + ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `potassium_recommendation < 0 == True` you can write `potassium_recommendation < 0`.

The complete code will look like that:

```py
potassium_recommendation = (73 + (200 * 0.21) + (500 * -0.565) + (200 * 500 * -0.0016))

if potassium_recommendation < 0:
  potassium_recommendation = 0

print potassium_recommendation
```